# How to implement substring function?

Tags: botframework

I have used  substring function in composer and the output should be the number extracted from the given value. Here the condition reaches to false branch.
By following the doc I have used below steps but I am not getting the output. It will be very helpful if somebody provides the solution.
[image]

I have used "= substring('${dialog.Str}', 4, 7) " as well.

I want 1234 only intger part to be stored in a property.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

- use like this ${substring(dialog.str, 4,4)} .. you will get the answers 1234 ..

substring - (string, starting Idx, total length)

Comment: Tried with = ${substring(dialog.str, 4, 4)} and ${substring(dialog.str, 4,4)}  but no luck.

Comment: Thanks @Vinoth Rajendran it worked instead of writing the logic  in if/else condition I tried that in sendrespose it worked.

Comment: first use in set property(assign in variable)  after that check in the condition it will work